# How to copy .iso file to VMware datastore, using playbooks

Tags: ansible, vmware

New in Ansible writing, can you please help me with coping an iso file to VMware datastore
As I understand, I can't take the file directly from network share, Is it right?

So I've used `net_get` module and then I will copy it to datastore

What I've did so far:

Vars:

```
---
vdatacenter: xxx
vdatastore: xxx
vcenter: xxx
vsrc: "\\nas\dir\file.iso"
vdst: "\datastore_folder\"
get_dst: "/tmp/"
vcenter_user: xxx
vcenter_pass: xxx
```

Copy playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: include vars
      include_vars:
        dir: group_vars

    - name: Copy to vCenter
      local_action:
        module: vsphere_copy
        host: '{{ vcenter }}'
        login: '{{ vcenter_user }}'
        password: '{{ vcenter_pass }}'
        src: '{{vsrc}}'
        datacenter: '{{vdatacenter}}'
        datastore: '{{vdatastore}}'
        path: '{{vdst}}'
```

Get playbook:

```
- hosts: localhost
  connection: local
  tasks:
    - name: include vars
      include_vars:
        dir: group_vars

    - name: Copy to source
      local_action:
        module: net_get
        src: '{{vsrc}}'
        dst: '{{get_dst}}'
        ansible_network_os: eos
```

Comment: Not sure what you mean by  _As I understand, I can't take the file directly from network share, Is it right?_ ... we store ISO images on an NFS share that's exposed to the vmware servers, and visible as a datastore in vCenter.   Pointing a new VM at an ISO for booting/install is trivial.

Comment: We have local datastores, NFS shares are visible but not as datastore

Answer (score 0):

I successfully used :
[vsphere_copy – Copy a file to a vCenter datastore](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/vsphere_copy_module.html)

```
- vsphere_copy:
    host: "{{ vcenter }}"
    login: "{{ vcenter_user }}"
    password: "{{ vcenter_pass }}"
    src: "{{ vsrc }}"
    datacenter: "{{ vdatacenter }}"
    datastore: "{{ vdatastore }}"
    path:  "{{ vdst}}"
  delegate_to: localhost
```

Tested on vSphere 6.5.0.13000